# How to add directive dynamically on the jquery plugin generated div

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive that initialize the jquery plugin

```
app.directive('floorplansMapplic',function($compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {              
            $(element).mapplic({
                source: 'apartment.json',
                height: 1080,
                animate: true,
                mapfill: true,
                sidebar: true,
                minimap: true,
                deeplinking: true,
                fullscreen: true,
                hovertip: true,
                developer: false,
                maxscale: 1,
                search: false,
            }); 
            $(element+" .mapplic-sidebar").append("<a href></a>"); //what is the right way to do this?
        }           
    };
});
```

The .mapplic-sidebar is dynamically generated by the jquery plugin by the $(element).mapplic({}); declaration. How to properly append the  element? Should I have to create another directive for that?

The HTML

```
<div id="mapplic" floorplans-mapplic></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do is first `$compile` it and then append it to particular div.

You can refer to below way, in which you can add it dynamically through controller as:

```
.directive( 'floorplansMapplic', function ( $compile ) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    link: function ( $scope, $element, attrs ) {
      $(element).mapplic({
                source: 'apartment.json',
                height: 1080,
                animate: true,
                mapfill: true,
                sidebar: true,
                minimap: true,
                deeplinking: true,
                fullscreen: true,
                hovertip: true,
                developer: false,
                maxscale: 1,
                search: false,
      }); 

      var el = $compile( "<a href></a>" )( $scope );
      $(element+" .mapplic-sidebar").append( el );

    }
  };
});
```

Hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I need the restrict to be 'A' as well.

Comment: IoQ, can you please share your code on fiddle or plunker?

Comment: Sure thing. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out. I realized that you have to add a delay after the jQuery generated the HTML in order for you to call the generated contents. Here's what I did. I used the angular $timeout and it's now working perfectly!

```
//initialize floorplans mapplic jquery
    app.directive('floorplansMapplic',function($compile,$timeout){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                $(element).mapplic({
                    source: 'apartment.json',
                    height: 1080,
                    animate: true,
                    mapfill: true,
                    sidebar: true,
                    minimap: true,
                    deeplinking: true,
                    fullscreen: true,
                    hovertip: true,
                    developer: false,
                    maxscale: 1,
                    search: false,
                }); 
                $timeout(function(){ //add a delay before appending a content
                    var elbtn = $compile('<a href ng-click="openModal()">Send a PDF</a>')(scope); //compile the content to be added
                    var elsidebarlist = $compile( ".mapplic-sidebar" )( scope ); //compile the content that was generated by the jquery plugin
                    $(elsidebarlist).append(elbtn);     
                }, 1000);               
            }           
        };
    });
```

Let me know if there's a better solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It might help you!! click for [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftfish/KyEr3/)

HTML code sample

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <addbuttonsbutton></addbuttonsbutton>
    <div id="space-for-buttons"></section>
</section>
```

AngularJS directive code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
}

//Directive that returns an element which adds buttons on click which show an alert on click
myApp.directive("addbuttonsbutton", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<button addbuttons>Click to add buttons</button>"
    }
});

//Directive for adding buttons on click that show an alert on click
myApp.directive("addbuttons", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
            scope.count++;
            angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-buttons')).append($compile("<div><button class='btn btn-default' data-alert="+scope.count+">Show alert #"+scope.count+"</button></div>")(scope));
        });
    };
});

//Directive for showing an alert on click
myApp.directive("alert", function(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
            console.log(attrs);
            alert("This is alert #"+attrs.alert);
        });
    };
});
```

And css code

```
section{
    padding: 2em;   
}
button{
    padding:0.3em;
    margin: 0.3em;
}
```

Comment: I saw this tutorial earlier and sorry but the idea is kinda far from my problem.